# In mobile Safari, website added to Home screen, shows gray bars on the top and bottom when navigating pages, how to make it full screen?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a multi page website. I add it to home screen in iPhone using "add to home screen" button in Share menu.

When I open it using the icon in the home screen, the website shows full screen. But when I go to any sub-page with a different route, like `example.com/page`, I see gray bars at the top and bottom, showing the address, navigation back and forward, "Done" button, share button, open in safari button.

How can I make it display full screen all the time?
Changing routing to use # is not an option.
It worked at some point in the past, but I had to remove the app, and can't make it work again

Comment: hmm are you using an pwa? there should be an manifest file where you can set the screen to fullscreen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out myself, it turns out that recently I removed `manifest.json` from the html file. Adding it back solved the problem!
Also, I found this page helpful in figuring out how manifest works https://web.dev/add-manifest/